# no matching function for call to 'make_function'

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to coding and have some issue which I generally do not really understand. 
The code will be shown as the following:

```
double SlowPionClusterCharge;
double cid;

StoreArray<PXDCluster> getPionClusters() {
  //float pxdClusterCharge;
  //float cid;
  float mcPDG;

  StoreArray<RecoTrack> m_RecoTracks;

  for (RecoTrack& recoTrack : m_RecoTracks) {
    for (PXDCluster& pxdcl : recoTrack.getRelationsFrom<PXDCluster>("PXDClusters")) {
      if (mcPDG == 211) {
        RecoTrack* track = recoTrack.getRelatedFrom<RecoTrack>("Tracks");
      } else {
        continue;
      }
      SlowPionClusterCharge = pxdcl.getCharge();
      cid = pxdcl.getSensorID().getID();
      if (pxdClusterCharge == 0) {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
}

VARIABLE_GROUP("PXD clusters");
REGISTER_VARIABLE("SlowPionClusterCharge(i)", SlowPionClusterCharge,   "[EventBased] cluster charge of slow pion in a event");
```

The error message is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'make_function'
REGISTER_VARIABLE("SlowPionClusterCharge(i)", SlowPionClusterCharge, "[EventBased] cluster charge of slow pion in a event");

/mnt/scratch/basf2/development/include/analysis/VariableManager/Manager.h:295:74: note: expanded from macro 'REGISTER_VARIABLE'
static Proxy VARMANAGER_MAKE_UNIQUE(_variableproxy)(std::string(name), Belle2::Variable::make_function(function), std::string(description));
```

Comment: You are not showing the definition of `REGISTER_VARIABLE` and `make_function` appears nowhere in the code. Please provide a [repro], otherwise there is no way to help you, except if there happesn to be someone here working on the same code base...

Comment: Or add tags regarding specific library, if this macro comes from a library.